# Determining the order of open tabs in Visual Studio (extension using EnvDTE)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I'm developing a Visual Studio extension in which I need to get a list of currently open documents(tabs) in the exact order they are displayed on screen.

For example, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lElek.png) should return: Program.cs, Class1.cs, Class2.cs, Class3.cs

The [EnvDTE.Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.documents.aspx) property does provide me with a list, but not in the order I need:

```cs
public List<Window> GetOpenTabsOrdered(DTE2 vsInstance)
{
   var openDocuments = vsInstance.Documents.Cast<Document>();
   return openDocuments.Select(x => x.ActiveWindow).ToList(); //wrong order
}
```

The Window.Left property (MSDN: Gets or sets the distance between the internal left edge of an object and the left edge of its container) also isn't particularly helpful in determining the correct order.

I tried subscribing to different events (e.g. DTE2.Events.WindowEvents.WindowMoved) but that didn't bring me anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

The automation model (EnvDTE) won't give you that information, you need to use some Visual Studio SDK service, for example the [IEnumWindowFrames Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ienumwindowframes.aspx). For each [IVsWindowFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivswindowframe.aspx), you can use the GetFramePos method or GetProperty methods. For example, you have the [VSFPROPID_MDIContainerID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vsfpropid3.aspx) property to get the group Id, [VSFPROPID_IsPinned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vsfpropid5.aspx) and VSFPROPID_IsProvisional to get if it is pinned, provisional, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your input, however I'm still struggling with this. I tried playing with GetDocumentWindowEnum and GetFramePos. Coordinates returned by GetFramePos are in fact exactly the same as Window.Left and Window.Top properties from EnvDTE. The problem with Left and Top is that they are always zero for all tabs except the active one (given they are all docked to the same window, see screenshot from my 1st post). If you could have a look at my code and point out any problems I would be really grateful: http://pastebin.com/uUKv6BeV